# perl regular expression match scalar plus punctuation

Tags: regex, perl

I have scalars (columns in a table) that have one or two email addresses separated by a comma. such as 'Joek@xyznco.com, jrancher@candyco.us' or 'jsmith@wellingent.com,mjones@wellingent.com' for several of these records I need to remove a bad/old email address and the trailing comma (*if one exists)*.

if jmsith@wellingent is no longer valid how do I remove that address and the trailing comma?

This only removes the address but leaves the comma.

```
my $general_email = 'jsmith@wellingent.com,mjones@wellingent.com';
my $bad_addr = 'jsmith@wellingent.com';

$general_email =~ s/$bad_addr//;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off without a regex but with list splitting:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub remove_bad {
    my ($full, $bad) = @_;
    my @emails = split /\s*,\s*/, $full;  # split at comma, allowing for spaces around the comma
    my @filtered = grep { $_ ne $bad } @emails;
    return join ",", @filtered;
}

print 'First: ' , remove_bad('me@example.org, you@example.org', 'me@example.org'), "\n";
print 'Last: ', remove_bad('me@example.org, you@example.org', 'you@example.org'), "\n";
print 'Middle: ', remove_bad('me@example.org, you@example.org, other@eample.org', 'you@example.org'), "\n";
```

First, `split` the bad email address list at the comma, creating an array. Filter that using `grep` to remove the bad address. `join` the remaining elements back into a string.

The above code prints:

> First: you@example.org
>
> Last: me@example.org
>
> Middle: me@example.org,other@eample.org

Comment: I'd replace the `!m/$bad/` with `$_ ne $bad` to avoid false-positives but besides that this seems the most robust solution.